# My python script does not publish velocity command to parrot drone in ROS

Tags: ros, gazebo-simu

I would like to publish velocities for my **ARDrone** using `/cmd_vel` topic using the below python script. But it does nothing. It does not publish the required information.
What is wrong in the below code?

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist

class KeyboardControl:
    def __init__(self):
        rospy.init_node('Script_controlling_ARDrone', anonymous=False)
        publisher = rospy.Publisher('/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=1)

        twist = Twist()
        twist.linear.x = 0
        twist.linear.y = 0
        twist.linear.z = -1
        twist.angular.x = 0
        twist.angular.y = 0
        twist.angular.z = 0.5

        publisher.publish(twist)


def main():
    try:
        kc = KeyboardControl()
        rospy.spin()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        rospy.loginfo("Shutting down")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: what is the output of `rostopic echo /cmd_vel`, and what is your `rostopic list`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does actually do something, however it's probably not noticeable. This is because it only publishes something *once* when the object is created. If you would like you publish periodically you should use a main run loop like so:

```
import numpy as np
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist

class KeyboardControl:
    def __init__(self):
        rospy.init_node('Script_controlling_ARDrone', anonymous=False)
        self.pub = rospy.Publisher('/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=1)
        self.rate = rospy.Rate(10) #10Hz


def main():
    try:
        kc = KeyboardControl()
        twist = Twist()
        twist.linear.x = 0
        twist.linear.y = 0
        twist.linear.z = -1
        twist.angular.x = 0
        twist.angular.y = 0
        twist.angular.z = 0.5
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            #Do any needed edits to the twist message here
            kc.pub.publish(twist)
            kc.rate.sleep()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        rospy.loginfo("Shutting down")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```